# The @ character in my URL causes an error in Unity3D for iOS

Tags: c#, email, error-handling, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get some values using he GET method

My url is

```
 
http://myweb.info/WNWS/WNS/RequestFBUser?UN=sona.mv&E=sona@gmail.com&FBN=SonaMv&FBI=100003833776130&FN=Sona&LN=Mv&DID=8f0043b4-84bc-461f-a7d0-477dadab9687&DT=I
```

The code I have is

```
void facebookLogin(string input){
    WWW www = new WWW(input);
    StartCoroutine(WaitForFbLogin(www));
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> The operation couldn't be completed. No such file or directory

The problem is with the '@' character in the email address. I can't avoid this.

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you need to do URL encoding (replace `@` with `%40`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape portions of the URL, but not all of it.  As mentioned in Unity's documentation for [EscapeURL](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.EscapeURL.html), that method is only intended for the parameters inserted into a URL meaning parameter names and values (though it can be used for portions of the path too if for example, there is a space in a directory name, etc.).  The "&" and "=" should remain as is since they determine boundaries between parameter names and values.  They would only need to be encoded if they are part of a parameter name or value since they would interfere with parsing later (i.e. the parser might think there is an additional parameter).

In this particular case, the "@" should be the only modification in the final output.

Comment: Myeah, that wasn't a very intelligent answer. I shouldn't write those in a hurry. Removed my answer. Perhaps update yours (so you no longer refer to it) and expand it a bit. But you're right.

Comment: @Bart Your link was great.  My initial thought is always to use .NET / Mono's functionality, so I would probably would have provided a link to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx).  But, for the sake of Assembly stripping and what not later, it is best to stick to Unity's functionality :)

Comment: Absolutely. But I should not answer questions pre-coffee. ;)